# Auto model creation through relationship Django

Tags: python, django, model

I got a model

```
class Incarico(models.Model):
    polizza = models.OneToOneField(Polizza, default=None, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and this model here

```
class Polizza(models.Model):
    partite = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

**i need to create First the Incarico model through a form compiled by some users, at the moment of creation of Incarico, Polizza needs to be created and linked with the same id.
How could i manage to do this?
Any help is appreciated!!!**

Comment: Why do you need `Polizza` to be created with the same id? The `polizza` field in `Incarico` is not a primary key, it is probably not a good idea to try to enforce it having the same id, since that might be much harder than one thinks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use signals to create the Polizza when the Incarico is created together:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Incarico)
def create_polizza(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        p = Polizza.objects.create()
        instance.polizza = p
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Thanks! how should i implement this one? i mean, where should i put this? and when should i call it?

Comment: models.py works but you could also make a signals.py file. Which ever works best for you